# IndexOutOfBoundsException for a Recursive call

Tags: java, recursion

This is my code which should remove the consecutive duplicates.

package Practice.Practice;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates {
    private static int i=1;
    public static List<String> detectDuplicates(List<String> chars) {
        if(i>chars.size())
            return chars;
        while(chars.get(i-1).equals(chars.get(i))) {
            chars.remove(i);
        }
        i++;
        return detectDuplicates(chars);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        List<String> chars = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("")));
        System.out.println(detectDuplicates(chars));

    }
}
```

it threw exception for the input "asssddaaffgff".

here is the Exception which was thrown :
**asssddaaffgff**

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:**
>   Index: 7, Size: 7     at
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)   at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.detectDuplicates(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:13)
>     at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.detectDuplicates(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:17)
>     at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.detectDuplicates(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:17)
>     at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.detectDuplicates(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:17)
>     at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.detectDuplicates(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:17)
>     at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.detectDuplicates(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:17)
>     at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.detectDuplicates(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:17)
>     at
>   Practice.Practice.RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.main(RemoveConsecutiveDuplicates.java:26)

Comment: `if(i>=chars.size())` - simple change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `while` loop:

```
while(chars.get(i-1).equals(chars.get(i)))
```

Here you are removing the elements. So the size of `List` and hence the value returned by `chars.size()` method changes.

Change `while` loop as following:

```
public static List<String> detectDuplicates(List<String> chars) {
    while(i<chars.size() && chars.get(i-1).equals(chars.get(i))) {
        chars.remove(i);
    }
    i++;

    if(i>chars.size())  return chars;
    return detectDuplicates(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the check in the `while` loop because the chars.size() is changing when you remove one. you can do it in the while it self.

```
...
while((i<chars.size()) && (chars.get(i-1).equals(chars.get(i)))) {
    chars.remove(i);
}
i++;
return detectDuplicates(chars);
...
```

Comment: You mean `i < chars.size()`.

Comment: Really if `i` is greater than equal to `chars.size` then what will `chars.get(i)` do?

Comment: Fix the wrong check. But the main idea was the `chars.get(i)` will be outOfBound if the `chars.remove(i) was the last char.